# Change input type of the keyboard C#

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-ce

I am looking for a way to change the input type of the keyboard in a WinForm application for a WindowsCE Device. We are using scanners with WindowsCE installed on them. By default, the input type can be changed by pressing the F8(Alpha) key on the scanner. Is there any way that this can be done in a C# code?

Answer (score 0):

Call this codes in a proper place

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo lang = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo('language-culture');
InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.FromCulture(lang);
```

and set your [language-culture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825488(v=cs.20).aspx). example "fa-IR" for farsi.